# Akka typed actor timeout

Tags: java, spring, akka

I am fairly new Akka world and was trying to use akka-spring integration. I am creating a typed Actor using Spring in the following manner.

```
<beans>
  <akka:typed-actor id="httpActor"
                    interface="com.biz.MyPOJO"
                    implementation="com.biz.MyPOJOImpl"
                    timeout="1000"
                    scope="protorype">
  </akka:typed-actor>
</beans>
```

However, in my use case, timeout is not a static concept, but the caller (which is an actor itself) should be able to set the timeout on the httpActor. Is there any way to pass dynamic timeout values to these actors?

EDIT : Akka version akka-actors-1.3-RC3

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.scalablesolutions.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-RC3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.scalablesolutions.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-typed-actor</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-RC3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: For answering this question it would be very helpful if you could include the Akka version you intend to run this on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to pass the timeout on a per-call basis.